# django url resolvers reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-urls

NoReverseMatch

I'm trying to make a basic website with the following urls

```
/congregation/ - home page
/congregation/archives - archives for that page
```

There are multiple 'congregations', each with an archive page.

I have the following url patterns:

church/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^', include('congregation.urls', namespace='congregation')),
]
```

church/congregation/urls.py

```
page_patterns = [
    url(r'^$', CongregationView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^archive/', SermonList.as_view(), name='archive')
]

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<congregation>\w{3,20})/', include(page_patterns, namespace='page'))
]
```

The pages display as I expect they should, but if I use links in header nav-bar, reverse lookup fails with this message

```
NoReverseMatch at /spokane/archive/
Reverse for 'archive' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'    not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<congregation>\\w{3,20})/archive/']
```

The error is caused by an invalid reverse match in the template

```
<li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'archives' %}active{% endif %}">
                <a href="{% url 'congregation:page:archive' %}">Archives</a></li>
```

I'm sure it's simple, but I'm having difficulty finding the solution.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your urlpattern `url(r'^(?P<congregation>\w{3,20})/', include(page_patterns, namespace='page'))` requires a `congregation` keyword. When you call your url resolver with `{% url 'congregation:page:archive' %}`, you are not providing a congregation keyword.

Ty`{% url 'congregation:page:archive' congregation=whatever %}`